# How to build video thumbnails sheet using pipe (ffmpeg + imagemagick)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, ffmpeg, imagemagick

How can I build video thumbnails sheet using pipe (ffmpeg + imagemagick) on windows without using temporary files?

Comment: I am voting to close this post as off-topic because it is actually not a qestion. Note that StackOverflow (like all sites in the StackExchange network) is a **Question and Answer site**, it is not a site for sharing some code you wrote. You can make this post on-topic if you reword it as a real question (following all the applicable [rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help)), which can be answered by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## UPDATE:

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1123899/how-to-generate-preview-video-for-web-with-a-few-frames-using-ffmpeg) is an update version of this post I wrote.

---

The script bellow creates a folder named `.\thumbnails` and store in it all video thumbnails, with the same name of the video file.

Fully configurable! No temporary files used! (uses pipe!)

Requires: ffmpeg and imagemagick.

[image]

```
set impath=C:\programs\imagemagick
set folder=C:\My videos
set frame=320x180
set tile=10x1
set vframes=10
set fps=1/20
    REM 1/60 -> 1 shot every 60s
set filesize=300
    REM max file size in Kb
set filetypes=*.mp4

pushd "%folder%"
if not exist thumbnails md thumbnails

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in (`dir /b %filetypes%`) do (
 if not exist "thumbnails\%%~nf.jpg" (
    ffmpeg.exe -threads 2 -y -i "%%f" -an -qscale:v 1 -vf fps=%fps% -vframes %vframes% -f image2pipe -vcodec ppm - ^
    | %impath%\convert - -resize %frame% -background transparent -gravity center -extent %frame% -sharpen 1x2 -quality 100%% miff:- ^
    | %impath%\montage - -tile %tile% -geometry %frame% -background black -quality 100%% -define jpeg:extent=%filesize%kb "thumbnails\%%~nf.jpg"
 )
)
```