# Using ImageMagick to efficiently stitch together a line scan image

Tags: ffmpeg, computer-vision, imagemagick, gige-sdk

I’m looking for alternatives for line scan cameras to be used in sports timing, or rather in the part where placing needs to be figured out. I found that common industrial cameras can readily match the speed of commercial camera solutions at >1000 frames per second. For my needs, usually the timing accuracy is not important, but the relative placing of athletes. I figured I could use one of the cheapest Basler, IDS or any other area scan industrial cameras for this purpose. Of course there are line scan cameras that can do a lot more than a few thousand fps (or hz), but it is possible to get area scan cameras that can do the required 1000-3000fps for less than 500€.

My holy grail would of course be the near-real time image composition capabilities of FinishLynx (or any other line scan system), basically this part: https://youtu.be/7CWZvFcwSEk?t=23s

The whole process I was thinking for my alternative is:

> - Use Basler Pylon Viewer (or other software) to record 2px wide images at the camera’s fastest read speed. For the camera I am
>     currently using it means it has to be turned on it’s side and the
>     height needs to be reduced, since it is the only way it will read
>     **1920x2px** frames @ >250fps
> - Make a program or batch script that then stitches these **1920x2px** frames together to, for example one second of recording **1000*1920x2px**
>     frames, meaning a resulting image with a resolution of **1920x2000px**
>     (Horizontal x Vertical).
> - Finally using the same program or another way, just rotate the image so it reflects how the camera is positioned, thus achieving an image
>     with a resolution of **2000x1920px** (again Horizontal x Vertical)
> - Open the image in an analyzing program (currently ImageJ) to quickly analyze results

I am no programmer, but this is what I was able to put together just using batch scripts, with the help of stackoverflow of course.

> - Currently recording a whole 10 seconds for example to disk as a raw/mjpeg(avi/mkv) stream can be done in real time.
> - Recording individual frames as TIFF or BMP, or using FFMPEG to save them as PNG or JPG takes ~20-60 seconds The appending and rotation
>     then takes a further ~45-60 seconds
>     **This all needs to be achieved in less than 60 seconds for 10 seconds of footage**(1000-3000fps @ 10s = 10000-30000 frames) , thus why I need something faster.

I was able to figure out how to be pretty efficient with ImageMagick:

```
magick convert -limit file 16384 -limit memory 8GiB -interlace Plane -quality 85 -append +rotate 270 “%folder%\Basler*.Tiff” “%out%”

#%out% has a .jpg -filename that is dynamically made from folder name and number of frames.
```

This command works and gets me 10000 frames encoded in about 30 seconds on a i5-2520m (most of the processing seems to be using only one thread though, since it is working at 25% cpu usage). This is the resulting image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuwK7.jpg (19686x1928px)

However since recording to TIFF frames using Basler’s Pylon Viewer takes just that much longer than recording an MJPEG video stream, I would like to use the MJPEG (avi/mkv) file as a source for the appending. I noticed FFMPEG has “image2pipe” -command, which should be able to directly give images to ImageMagick. I was not able to get this working though:

```
   $ ffmpeg.exe -threads 4 -y -i "Basler acA1920-155uc (21644989)_20180930_043754312.avi" -f image2pipe - | convert - -interlace Plane -quality 85 -append +rotate 270 "%out%" >> log.txt
    ffmpeg version 3.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
      configuration: –enable-gpl –enable-version3 –enable-sdl2 –enable-bzlib –enable-fontconfig –enable-gnutls –enable-iconv –enable-libass –enable-libbluray –enable-libfreetype –enable-libmp3lame –enable-libopenjpeg –enable-libopus –enable-libshine –enable-libsnappy –enable-libsoxr –enable-libtheora –enable-libtwolame –enable-libvpx –enable-libwavpack –enable-libwebp –enable-libx264 –enable-libx265 –enable-libxml2 –enable-libzimg –enable-lzma –enable-zlib –enable-gmp –enable-libvidstab –enable-libvorbis –enable-cuda –enable-cuvid –enable-d3d11va –enable-nvenc –enable-dxva2 –enable-avisynth –enable-libmfx
      libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
      libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
      libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
      libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
      libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
      libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
      libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
      libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
    Invalid Parameter - -interlace
    [mjpeg @ 000000000046b0a0] EOI missing, emulating
    Input #0, avi, from 'Basler acA1920-155uc (21644989)_20180930_043754312.avi’:
      Duration: 00:00:50.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1356 kb/s
        Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x2, 1318 kb/s, 200 fps, 200 tbr, 200 tbn, 200 tbc
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mjpeg (native))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    Output #0, image2pipe, to ‘pipe:’:
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
        Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc), 1920x2, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 200 fps, 200 tbn, 200 tbc
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 mjpeg
        Side data:
          cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
    Error writing trailer of pipe:: Invalid argument
    frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=1.6 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.01 bitrate= 358.4kbits/s speed=0.625x
    video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%
    Conversion failed!
```

If I go a bit higher for the height, I no longer get the “[mjpeg @ 000000000046b0a0] EOI missing, emulating” -error. However the whole thing will only work with <2px high/wide footage.

edit: Oh yes, I can also use `ffmpeg -i file.mpg -r 1/1 $filename%03d.bmp` or `ffmpeg -i file.mpg $filename%03d.bmp` to extract all the frames from the MJPEG/RAW stream. However this is an extra step I do not want to take. (just deleting a folder of 30000 jpgs takes 2 minutes alone…)

Can someone think of a working solution for the piping method or a totally different alternative way of handling this?

Comment: Add a `-c copy` in the ffmpeg command after the avi name and try.

Comment: No help, it isn’t used here in a question trying to solve related problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39457296/how-to-build-video-thumbnails-sheet-using-pipe-ffmpeg-imagemagick

Still get:
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
Error writing trailer of pipe:: Invalid argument

(the script listed in the answer gives the same errors)

Comment: I'm lost trying to understand what you want to do! You have 3,000 TIFF files that you want to make into an MP4 file? You have an MJPG file that you want take the frames from and append to make a cartoon strip? You already have a video but you want to add some frames? I find it very hard to guess what you actually are trying to achieve...

Comment: Do you have some images before and after processing?

Comment: Proper IM 7 syntax is to use magick only, not magick convert and not convert. Also IM 7 is less forgiving about command order than IM 6 and one should read the input images earlier before other operators. So better would be `magick -limit file 16384 -limit memory 8GiB  “%folder%\Basler*.Tiff” -append +rotate 270 -interlace Plane -quality 85  “%out%”`

Comment: Continued: I have never seen the use of +rotate. As far as I know it is only -rotate. See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#rotate. So the command should be `magick -limit file 16384 -limit memory 8GiB “%folder%\Basler*.Tiff” -append -rotate 270 -interlace Plane -quality 85 “%out%”`

Comment: @MarkSetchell, When recording with Pylon Viewer (from Basler SDK) I can record 1000-3000fps without first buffering to RAM when recording a “stream” or in other words to a video file. If save each individual frame (1920x2px) as TIFF files, my SSD cannot keep up and Pylon will buffer to memory. This takes too much time compared to real time viewing of a professional finish line camera, where the picture is provided by a line scan camera, that already provides the “whole” images.

Comment: @MarkSetchell This is what I put together (from TIFFs): https://i.imgur.com/OD4RqL7.jpg (the black lines are from PWM of the lighting used). This is what I am trying to achieve: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fe-j2K0f5kQ

Comment: @fmw42: Yeah, I can’t anything about using +/-, but for me **it seems to work standalone regardless**.. I think that was just a typo where i put the + to the rotate command instead of the previous -append/+append.. I cannot seem to get this to work with a command like “ffmpeg -i 20180930-203951.mkv -c:v ppm -f image2pipe - | convert - output.gif” either, which lead me to believe the problem is somwhere else. I just learned that JPEG/MJPEG supposedly only handles 8x8 “blocks, which my 1920x2 definitely don’t have in HxV. Imagemagick will convert to 1920x2 jpg-files from the tiffs still.

Comment: Sorry, I still have no idea if you are starting with a large number of TIFFs and trying to make an MP4, or if you have an MP4 and are trying to make a JPEG. I don't know if you are trying to feed the output from some Basler software into ImageMagick and then into `ffmpeg`. Or if you are trying to stitch some JPEGs to make an animated GIF.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have updated the question a bit. Basically working with TIFFs or individual image files the whole process works, but since I am trying to achieve real-time (or as fast as possible) capability of recording, appending frames and viewing the output, it is necessary to use a video stream for recording. I can record as RAW or MJPEG stream (avi) directly to the disk from Pylon Viewer, while it is not possible to do the same for TIFFs because Pylon then save to RAM before saving to disk! To achieve the fastest method, I can only think avi->ffmpeg->imagemagick is “direct” enough.

Comment: Ok, I am starting to understand now. You don't actually have any TIFFs, you actually have an AVI video where each frame is 1920x2 pixels and you want to stitch those together, side-by-side as fast as possible and make a JPEG image - is that correct? Can you therefore share the AVI video?

Comment: Your `ffmpeg` command isn't working because you used `ffmpeg ... | convert - ...` which started Windows `CONVERT.EXE` rather than ImageMagick and that is why it printed `Invalid Parameter -interlace`. You need to use `ffmpeg ... | magick - ...` instead.

Comment: @MarkSetchell You are right… I got further, thank you. However it seems I need something like https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18320&p=71150 The image2pipe doesn’t function like I thought it could (it only reads one image… obviously) A batch script loop isn’t going to achieve what I need. Well, time to boot Ubuntu then I guess. I tried using cygwin too, but couldn’t get “pnmnoraw” to work...

Comment: @MarkSetchell or maybe not… Since IM7 should have similar features to the script? It definitely seems like the method I am using now isn’t the correct one. I see no increase in RAM usage when trying the same with full frame images… Thus the images from the FFMPEG output are just going to NUL… Or maybe I still need a loop? (which won’t be sufficient..) hmm

Comment: I think I figured it out: -f `ffmpeg -i %source% image2pipe -vcodec ppm - | magick convert -interlace Plane -quality 85 -append - - | magick convert -rotate 270 - %out%` For some reason I cannot do the rotation in the first convert command… This seems to be about 10-20x faster than the TIFF method!

Comment: It is already not related to this question.. But perhaps it would be possible to stream the resulting image to a preview program? Another option would also be to create full-frame video, where the line scan would stream in from other side and out from the other… hmm

Comment: Can you share your AVI please so I can try some ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had another go at this to see if I could speed up my other answer by doing things a couple of different ways - hence a different answer. I used the same synthetic videoclip that I generated in the other answer to test with.

Rather than pass the 2x1920 scanlines into **ImageMagick** for it to append together and write as a JPEG, I did the following:

- created the full output frame up front in a C++ program, and then looped reading in a 2x1920 scanline on each iteration and stuffed that into the correct position in the output frame, and
- when the entire sequence has been read, compressed it into a JPEG using turbo-jpeg and wrote it disk.

As such, **ImageMagick** is no longer required. The entire program now runs in around 1.3 seconds rather than the 10.3 seconds via **ImageMagick**.

Here is the code:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// stitch.cpp
// Mark Setchell
//
// Read 2x1920 RGB frames from `ffmpeg` and stitch into 20000x1920 RGB image.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <turbojpeg.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int frames = 10000;
   int height = 1920;
   int width  = frames *2;

   // Buffer in which to assemble complete output image (RGB), e.g. 20000x1920
   unsigned char *img = new unsigned char [width*height*3];

   // Buffer for one scanline image 1920x2 (RGB)
   unsigned char *scanline = new unsigned char[2*height*3];

   // Output column
   int ocol=0;

   // Read frames from `ffmpeg` fed into us like this:
   // ffmpeg -threads 4 -y -i video.mov -frames 10000 -vf "transpose=1" -f image2pipe -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 - | ./stitch
   for(int f=0;f<10000;f++){
      // Read one scanline from stdin, i.e. 2x1920 RGB image...
      ssize_t bytesread = read(STDIN_FILENO, scanline, 2*height*3);

      // ... and place into finished frame
      // ip is pointer to input image
      unsigned char *ip = scanline;
      for(int row=0;row<height;row++){
         unsigned char *op = &(img[(row*width*3)+3*ocol]);
         // Copy 2 RGB pixels from scanline to output image
         *op++ = *ip++; // red
         *op++ = *ip++; // green
         *op++ = *ip++; // blue
         *op++ = *ip++; // red
         *op++ = *ip++; // green
         *op++ = *ip++; // blue
      }
      ocol += 2; 
   }

   // Now encode to JPEG with turbo-jpeg
   const int JPEG_QUALITY = 75;
   long unsigned int jpegSize = 0;
   unsigned char* compressedImage = NULL;
   tjhandle _jpegCompressor = tjInitCompress();

   // Compress in memory
   tjCompress2(_jpegCompressor, img, width, 0, height, TJPF_RGB,
          &compressedImage, &jpegSize, TJSAMP_444, JPEG_QUALITY,
          TJFLAG_FASTDCT);

   // Clean up
   tjDestroy(_jpegCompressor);

   // And write to disk
   ofstream f("result.jpg", ios::out | ios::binary);
   f.write (reinterpret_cast<char*>(compressedImage), jpegSize);
}
```

---

**Notes:**

**Note 1:** In order to pre-allocate the output image, the program needs to know how many frames are coming in advance - I did not parameterize that, I just hard-coded 10,000 but it should be easy enough to change.

One way to determine the number of frames in the video sequence is this:

```
ffprobe -v error -count_frames -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_frames -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 video.mov
```

**Note 2:** Note that I compiled the code with a couple of switches for performance:

```
g++-8 -O3 -march=native stitch.cpp -o stitch
```

**Note 3:** If you are running on Windows, you may need to re-open `stdin` in binary mode before doing:

```
read(STDIN_FILENO...)
```

**Note 4:** If you don't want to use turbo-jpeg, you could remove everything after the end of the main loop, and simply send a [NetPBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) `PPM` image to **ImageMagick** via a pipe and let it do the JPEG writing. That would look like, very roughly:

```
writeToStdout("P6 20000 1920 255\n");
writeToStdout(img, width*height*3);
```

Then you would run with:

```
ffmpeg ... | ./stitch | magick ppm:-  result.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you!! Didn’t get it running on Windows yet, but this seems like the definitive solution! Probably cannot get faster than this without GPU acceleration :) A couple seconds is plenty fast enough!

Comment: Ditch that, this seems to get me a result! stackoverflow.com/a/1613677/5776626

Comment: Any idea why some files might fail to produce an image if the last x% of frames are not left out? On some files it can be something like 1-2%, but on others might not stitch at all or require even more frames to be taken out… I’m suspecting something with the way the AVI files are recorded, though FFMPEG can still read the frames from every file. Examples: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uw2262rboxqkkck/AAD9gfcscFMa_fjJdmYAld_Ba?dl=0 Two of them are just black captures, while the one ending with 192616999 contains “test footage”

Comment: Of course it is simply because of the 65,535 limitation on jpg width :) I guess I need to go to PNG :/

Comment: If anyone is interested, this is what I managed to get together with the whole thing! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WWLj3zVCJI&list=PLgq9ECzoG1QR_UR8c9vYhLEPSl-zEpFyL&index=4&t=1s

Answer (score 3):

I generated a sample video of 10,000 frames, and did some tests. Obviously, my machine is not the same specification as yours, so results are not directly comparable, but I found it is quicker to let `ffmpeg` transpose the video and the pipe it into **ImageMagick** as raw RGB24 frames.

I found that I can convert a 10 second movie into a 20,000x1920 pixel JPEG in 10.3s like this:

```
ffmpeg -threads 4 -y -i video.mov -frames 10000 -vf "transpose=1" -f image2pipe -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 - | convert -depth 8 -size 2x1920 rgb:- +append result.jpg
```

The resulting image looks like this:

[image]

---

I generated the video like this with `CImg`. Basically it just draws a Red/Green/Blue splodge successively further across the frame till it hits the right edge, then starts again at the left edge:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cimg_library;

int main()
{
   // Frame we will fill
   CImg<unsigned char> frame(1920,2,1,3);

   int width =frame.width();
   int height=frame.height();

   // Item to draw in frame - created with ImageMagick
   // convert xc:red xc:lime xc:blue +append -resize 256x2\! splodge.ppm
   CImg<unsigned char> splodge("splodge.ppm");

   int offs  =0;

   // We are going to output 10000 frames of RGB raw video
   for(int f=0;f<10000;f++){
      // Generate white image
      frame.fill(255);

      // Draw coloured splodge at correct place
      frame.draw_image(offs,0,splodge);
      offs = (offs + 1) % (width - splodge.width());

      // Output to ffmpeg to make video, in planar GBR format
      // i.e. run program like this
      // ./main | ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format gbrp -video_size 1920x2 -i - -c:v h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mov
      char* s=reinterpret_cast<char*>(frame.data()+(width*height));   // Get start of G plane
      std::cout.write(s,width*height);                                // Output it
      s=reinterpret_cast<char*>(frame.data()+2*(width*height));       // Get start of B plane
      std::cout.write(s,width*height);                                // Output it
      s=reinterpret_cast<char*>(frame.data());                        // Get start of R plane
      std::cout.write(s,width*height);                                // Output it
   }
}
```

The splodge is 192x2 pixels and looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I was after… I think this it is the answer! The method is definitely the fastest at the moment. Though I’d still like a bit of speed, so will think about accepting it for a few days yet. Thanks!! I should’ve realized that of course ImageMagick’s “convert -rotate” cannot be the fastest method since it isn’t using all of the cpu cores… With FFMPEG running transpose on all of them, of course it is going to make everything a lot faster! Now I can freeze my computer nicely, too :) (also good)

Comment: I suspect it can be made to go even faster. At the moment, Imagemagick has to allocate space for an image, then re-allocate space to append the next one, then re-allocate space to append the next one, I think. It should be possible to determine how many frames there are at the start, then allocate a sufficiently long image for the whole lot and simply put the new pixels in as they arrive, but unfortunately you haven't provided a representative video so I had to do it the hard way.

Comment: Ok. I think I can then figure out to check the number of frames in batch script and input it as variable. (I did calculate the amount of TIFFs in a folder previously too..) All of the files will have a varying amount of frames. I will try to put together something that makes sense as a linescan for a example if you still want? I had deleted the previous footage, and only have completely black captures, which didn’t make sense to share, as it might have confused things even further. For what I can see, you have generated exactly same type of source material that I would get from the camera.